# Is there a way to get an s3 object stream chunk by chunk using AWSSDK in dotnet?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream

We have a system that gets an event from AWS S3 when a new object is PUT.

We have a bunch of services registered that we pass the `GetObjectResponse` to.  Each service examines the `GetObjectResponse` via the `ResponseStream`.  If one object "passes" on handling the object, it goes to the next one and so on.  But, once the `ResponseStream` is started to be read by one service, the `Position` cannot be set to 0.

So, the `GetObjectResponse` is refreshed for each service to examine it.  Then, once the service is found, it has to be refreshed again.

Is there any way to prevent these multiple calls to `GetObjectAsync`?

We get the object using:

```
var s3 = this.GetProvider().GetRequiredService<IAmazonS3>();
using GetObjectResponse getObjectResponse = await s3.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest() { BucketName = bucketName, Key = objectKey });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 is offering a feature called [byte-range fetches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html), it allows us to fetch large files from s3 in chunk by chunk methods.

```
var s3 = this.GetProvider().GetRequiredService<IAmazonS3>();
using GetObjectResponse getObjectResponse = await s3.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest() { BucketName = bucketName, Key = objectKey, Range='bytes=START_BYTE_ID-END_BYTE_ID' }); #Place your values in
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out.  Thanks.